# PHP Datetime ISO8601 conversion

Tags: php, datetime, iso8601

I'm formatting a date in ISO8601 with Datetime and then i restore it, but restoring don't give me original value.

Test snippet

```
$d = new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
$formatted =  $d->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
$restored  =  \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ISO8601, $formatted);
var_dump($d);
var_dump($formatted);
var_dump($restored);
```

Result

```
object(DateTime)[5]
  public 'date' => string '-0001-11-30 00:00:00' (length=20)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Rome' (length=11)

string '-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0100' (length=25)


boolean false
```

PHP version PHP 5.4.28

Answer (score 0):

0th of Nulluary is not a date that exists. PHP does some time math with it (e.g. the 13th month becomes the 1st month of the following year, values <1 work the other way backwards), so you get what you get. There is no "right" answer for `0000-00-00`, it's nonsense. It works fine with real dates.

Comment: So the string '-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0100' generated by ->format(\DateTime::ISO8601) is actually not a valid ISO8601 date?

Comment: The problem with parsing using `createFromFormat` will be that `DateTime::ISO8601` expects `Y` as the first token, and it encounters a `-` instead, which breaks the parsing. The date may well be valid, but the parsing fails. I don't know off the top of my head what the solution to parsing a negative year with this is.

Comment: If anything the question boils down to: *How to parse a negative date with `DateTime::createFromFormat` correctly*, which you may want to open a new question for.

Comment: Thank you. Created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827328/php-datetime-fail-to-convert-negative-iso8601-date