# PHP Datetime fail to convert negative ISO8601 date

Tags: php, datetime, iso8601

Converting a negative date with DateTime get me false

Test code

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ISO8601, '-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0100'));
```

Result

```
boolean false
```

Expected result

```
object(DateTime)[5]
  public 'date' => string '-0001-11-30 00:00:00' (length=20)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 1
  public 'timezone' => string '+01:00' (length=6)
```

(or something similar)

P.S. The negative date string was created with $d->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);

PHP version PHP 5.4.28

Comment: Why not just use `new DateTime('-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0100');`? And DateTime class cannot know that `+01:00` offset is `Europe/Rome` timezone...

Comment: You are right about expected timezone, fixed the question. So I must infer that \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ISO8601, ... ) is buggy?

Comment: `ISO 8601 prescribes, as a minimum, a four-digit year [YYYY] to avoid the year 2000 problem. It therefore represents years from 0000 to 9999, year 0000 being equal to 1 BC and all others AD. However, years prior to 1583 are not automatically allowed by the standard. Instead "values in the range [0000] through [1582] shall only be used by mutual agreement of the partners in information interchange."[`

Comment: So I suspect that it's `format()` that's potentially buggy rather than `createFromFormat()`

Comment: @Mark I'd think `format` doesn't care about the ISO spec in particular. `DateTime::ISO8601` is just a preset for the format string after all, not a flag which switches on ISO-compliant processing. The question is rather how can negative numbers be parsed by `DateTime::createFromFormat`, or is that simply not possible?

Comment: Well the ISO8601 spec doesn't support negative year values, so createFromFormat() is probably complaining because there's a leading `-` sign where there shouldn't be one.... so I suspect it isn't possible to parse that value.... for me, the question is why format() should have returned a value of -0001 for the year

Comment: @Mark Consider that `DateTime` as such doesn't promise any ISO compliance at all as far as I'm aware. Again, `DateTime::ISO8601` is merely the string `Y-m-d\TH:i:sO`, nothing more. `DateTime::format('Y')` returns negative values of its own volition regardless of what ISO has to say about it.

Answer (score -1):

According to manual of [Format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
 public string DateTime::format ( string $format )
```

where

```
$format

Format accepted by date().
```

and if you look in [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$d->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
```

should be

```
$d->format("c")
```

because "c" is according to format in [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

> ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)

In my test   `$d->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);` outputs

> 2015-09-15T00:00:00+0200

while

```
$d->format("c");
```

outputs

> 2015-09-15T00:00:00+02:00

I hope it helps.