# php DateTime before 0 (Historical ACN dates)

Tags: php, datetime

I've made a search in stackoverflow about ACN dates, but the only results I have are dates after 0, between 0 and 1000, or between 0 and 1970.

I need to handle persons birthdates, but I have a lot of persons born before Year 0.
\juliantojd and \jdtojulian do not help me because the method should return a DateTime object.

How to build a valid DateTime instance before year 0?

If I use \DateTime::createFromFormat, with first arg like 'c' or \DateTime::ISO8601 the return value is false.

PS :

1. I found same question here : [PHP Datetime fail to convert negative ISO8601 date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827328/php-datetime-fail-to-convert-negative-iso8601-date)
   But the answer doesn't take negative year in count.
2. I found also https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76785, may be a part of the answer (but I need to convert separators from / to -)

Thanks.

Comment: Forget about old birthday dates. It makes no sense to speak of birthday dates, when there were a very different calendar (and way to describe days). Do you mean: Roman calendar, Greek calendar, Hebriew calendar, etc.? If you want to do it, you should invent your fictional calendar, and then use it (and implement it). BTW, what it is "ACN"? Do you mean AC / BCE?

Comment: `new DateTime('-9999-01-01')` appears to be working fine for me on a 64bit system? https://3v4l.org/fgfPE

Comment: Indeed, new DateTime('-9999-01-01') works, but not createFromFormat. And new DateTime('-9999/01/01') don't work.

I solved this by looking for the presence or not of a minus sign before the date. It works, but it's not elegant.

Comment: Where are you receiving the date in the `-9999/01/01` format from? Is this what you're storing? Is it under your control?

Comment: @El_Vanja : It's not under my control, because we use a shared database, populated mainly by a java application. the [-]?Y/m/d is the format stored into db, because they cannot store as date a lot of dates.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi: ACN means Ante Christus Natum. We have a lot of philosphs in database who were born before year 0. When I write "birthday", it means more "birth day". We need to know these dates.

Comment: @all: thanks for your answers. I parse the string and convert it into a [-]?Y-m-d format and it works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is to have a date. Look just recently: Prince Philip, duke of Edinburgh: which it is his birth day and of Benjamin Franklin? Both where born with a different calendar compared what they used for most of their life. So you have a real and a "normalized" date. And good luck to find the birth day of ancient people: usually they may have a dead date, but birth date is unknown (as it was common on that time). Please: do not use a date field, but a text (with explanation), or you will add confusion to readers [a note is important to compare with different sources]

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi  thanks

Answer (score 0):

For negative years up to -9999, DateTime only accepts the format -yyyy-mm-dd. Formats like "-1234-8-9" or "-1234/08/09" produce errors. No manipulation is allowed with relative expressions like "-3 Days 2021/08/01". In the general case it is therefore not sufficient to only check the first character for "-". I chose a regular expression for the formats -Y-m-d and -Y/m/d for testing.

```
  $input = preg_replace_callback(
    '~^(-\d{1,4})([\-/])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,2})( |$)~',
    function($m){
      return sprintf('%05d-%02d-%02d%s',$m[1],$m[3],$m[4],$m[5]);
    },
    $input
  );
```

A simple test:

```
$tests = [
  "-1234-01-01","-34/4/5","2021-04-05 09:45","-3056-01-01","-9999/1/1",
  "-35 Days 00:00","-35-8/2"
];

foreach($tests as $input){
  $inputMod = preg_replace_callback(
    '~^(-\d{1,4})([\-/])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,2})( |$)~',
    function($m){
      return sprintf('%05d-%02d-%02d%s',$m[1],$m[3],$m[4],$m[5]);
    },
    $input
  );
  $dt = date_create($inputMod);
  if($dt){
    echo $input.' ==> '.$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>\n";
  }
  else echo $input." ==> Error<br>\n";
}
```

Result today:

```
-1234-01-01 ==> -1234-01-01 00:00:00
-34/4/5 ==> -0034-04-05 00:00:00
2021-04-05 09:45 ==> 2021-04-05 09:45:00
-3056-01-01 ==> -3056-01-01 00:00:00
-9999/1/1 ==> -9999-01-01 00:00:00
-35 Days 00:00 ==> 2021-03-17 00:00:00
-35-8/2 ==> Error
```